# Why must certain functions on a group take commutators to the identity?

Tags: representation-theory

[image: from sternberg group theory and physics]

My question is about the identity pictured above. Can't figure out why it is true.

Comment: Sorry, my neck does not twist in that direction. Do not paste in unreadable scans of other sources. Instead, please type out the identity that you want us to examine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is poorly worded. What is $\kappa$ a function to? For instance, if $G$ is a non-commutative group and $\kappa$ is the identity function, the result is false. If $\kappa$ maps to a commutative group, however, then note that

$$\kappa(1)=\kappa(1\cdot 1)=\kappa(1)\cdot \kappa(1)$$
so $\kappa(1)$ is the identity in the codomain. Also,

$$\kappa(1)=\kappa(a\cdot a^{-1})=\kappa(a)\cdot \kappa(a^{-1})$$

so $\kappa(a^{-1})=\kappa(a)^{-1}$ in the codomain. So if the codomain is commutative,

$$\kappa(aba^{-1}b^{-1})=\kappa(a)\kappa(b)\kappa(a^{-1})\kappa(b^{-1})=\kappa(a)\kappa(b)\kappa(a)^{-1}\kappa(b)^{-1}=1.$$

Comment: I think the codomain is linear transformations of a complex vector space, so not commutative. It's possible that the codomain is just the complex numbers though, in which case yes. Is that what seems to be the intended meaning?

Comment: It seems that the text is considering one-dimensional representations, in which case the codomain is commutative.